# Where i will find the swatches file?

Tags: magento2.3.3

I want to change code for text swatches that render on the list page in Magento 2 in the configurable products. I have changed files in Magento_Swatches but no change is applying on the frontend.

[image]

Comment: check this files: **vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml** and 
**vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js**

Comment: vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js this is the file which worked